# runtime exception when i click the button to load data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I want to retrieve the data from a `SQLite` database and show it in the `RecyclerView` but it shows an error

((Adapter class))

```
public class myAdapert extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapert.myViewHolder> {
ArrayList<Model_class> modelClassArrayList;

public myAdapert(ArrayList<Model_class> modelClassArrayList) {
    this.modelClassArrayList = modelClassArrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View customView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.custom_row,viewGroup,false);
    myViewHolder myviewHolder = new myViewHolder(customView);
    return myviewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
    Model_class model_class = modelClassArrayList.get(i);
    myViewHolder.author.setText(model_class.getAuthor());
    myViewHolder.title.setText(model_class.getTitle());
    myViewHolder.cost.setText(model_class.getCost());
    myViewHolder.quantity.setText(model_class.getQuantity());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return modelClassArrayList.size();
}

public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView author,title;
    TextView cost,quantity;
    public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        author = itemView.findViewById(R.id.authortxt);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTxt);
        cost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.costTxt);
        quantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantityTxt);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the line 34 of your adapter?

Answer (score 0):

As cost and quantity are numbers, I suppose, you should convert it to String explicitly, to prevent resourse manager from loading drawables:

```java
    myViewHolder.cost.setText(String.valueOf(model_class.getCost()));
    myViewHolder.quantity.setText(String.valueOf(model_class.getQuantity()));
```